# Scala Anonymous Function - does not behave as I expected

Tags: scala

I am a scala newbie.

I would like to understand why this code does not behave as I expect it

```
def invokeFunc( myFunc: () => String ){
    println(myFunc())
  }

  def callInvoker(){
     invokeFunc({ return "this is a string" })
  }
```

When I invoke "callInvoker" I get nothing. I expected a print for "this is a string", but instead nothing returns. Why?

Comment: Did you intentionally leave out the '=' behind the function signature?

Comment: Can you please explain the question?

Comment: def functionName( arg: Arg ): ReturnType = { Body } is the standard definition of a function. You left out the '=' which tells the compiler your function is returning Unit (void in the Java world).

Comment: Not intentionally. I know a lot of languages and it is sometimes confusing. I add ";" in python automatically do concatenations in Java.. Just didn't have the chance to get used to scala yet. Will try to stick to standards. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `return` does not return from your anonymous function, but from the enclosing method.
So when doing `invokeFunc({ return "this is a string" })` you are effectively returning from `callInvoker` (with the value `"this is a string"`, which is just discarded as `callInvoker` is of type `Unit`).

A corrected code would be:

```
def invokeFunc( myFunc: () => String ){
  println(myFunc())
}

def callInvoker(){
   invokeFunc{() => "this is a string" }
}

callInvoker()
```

Now your anonymous function actually returns `"this is a string"` (any function/method returns its last expression, unless an explicit `return` is encountered, but as I explained `return` applies to the enclosing method and never to an anonymous function).

Comment: Great thanks. I will accept your answer once the site will allow me. (minimum time limit).